# Interval Scheduler processes - the end of the previous function

Tags: node.js, cron, npm

I create this cronjob:

```
new CronJob('* * * * * *', function(){

    End();
}
}, null, true, "America/Los_Angeles");
```

and I want that it run again **just after** the previous ***End()*** function is finish.

How can I do it?

Comment: so you want to execute that every minutes and also after each end ? pretty much.

Comment: Yes, How can I do it?